# How to dynamically add an audio file to the div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to add an audio file dynamically. I have declared the tags like

```
<div>
  <audio id="myaudio">
  </audio>
</div>
```

Now i want to add the source dynamically. How can i add to the div or audio tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this

```
$('#myaudio').attr('src','track1.mp3');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) like this:
`$('audio').append('<source src="yourfile.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />');`

See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/hCkPY/1/